# refetch() data not working on apollo graphql

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, apollo-client, subgraph

I have a react component that fetches data from Subgraph using Apollo Graphql. The query takes `walletAddress` as a variables and needs to refetch new data every time `walletAddress` changes.

This is my current approach. When `walletAddress` changes, the `useEffect` hook is properly activated and `refetch()` is called. But the data never loads and `loading` is stuck as `true`.

When I check the network requests, the `refetch()` call is never made on the backend. Any tips on how to get this `refetch()` call to work would be greatly appreciated!

```
const BidsTable = ({walletAddress}) => {
 
  const {data, loading, refetch} = useQuery(GET_BIDS, {
    variables: {
      addr: walletAddress,
    }  
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    refetch();
  }, [walletAddress]);

return (
    ...
)


}
```

Comment: I had the similar problem but the `useLazyQuery` manual calls were not working except the 1st one. And loading was not even changing. Reading your post I rewrote `useLazyQuery` to use `useQuery's` refetch and now it's working. So you can try moving to 'useLazyQuery'.  Maybe somebody can clarify what's going on?

Comment: you should try to call refecth() in the walletAddress change handler